# Galaxy S5 S Voice unable to detect current location

Tags: location-services, s-voice

I used to use S Voice to bring up navigation: "Navigate to 123 Elm Street Springfield"  And it would take me directly to google maps navigation.  Now when I do that it says, "Sorry, I am unable to detect your current location.  Please check your settings and try again."

But when I go to google maps and ask it to navigate, it does so without problem.  So location services are working.

What setting do I need to change?

Software version: G900PVPU2BOD3
Hardware version: G900P.04
Android version: 5.0
Model number: SM-G900P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my carrier's support, I found the answer.  **Settings > Location > Mode > High Accuracy** solved the problem.